# Strange value from ImportXML

Tags: google-sheets, web-scraping, xpath, google-sheets-formula

I use the following importXML:

```
=IMPORTXML("http://www.morningstar.se/guide/quicktake?id=0P00009NT9"; "/html/body/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[4]/div[1]/div[3]/table[1]/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]")
```

to scrape text into my cell and two cells across the row where I get the latest GAV: `116,17 SEK`.

I would like to use that number value. I have tried with `=LEFT(A3;3)` but that only gives an error.

How might I retrieve it?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if 'SEK' is always going to be at the end of the string, but for your present example see if this works:

```
=ArrayFormula(REGEXEXTRACT(JOIN(" "; IMPORTXML("http://www.morningstar.se/guide/quicktake?id=0P00009NT9"; "/html/body/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[4]/div[1]/div[3]/table[1]/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]")); {"^(.+)\s\d"\ "([0-9,]+)"}))
```

If you only need the number and not the preceding text:

```
=ArrayFormula(REGEXEXTRACT(JOIN(" "; IMPORTXML("http://www.morningstar.se/guide/quicktake?id=0P00009NT9"; "/html/body/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[4]/div[1]/div[3]/table[1]/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]")); "([0-9,]+)"))+0
```

Answer (score 1):

You might wrap your formula in:

```
1*substitute(index( <your formula> ;3);" SEK";"")
```